# How ReactNative Tablet Support works?

Tags: react-native

I have currently placed 1x, 2x, 3x images . It look fine in all Android & Ios Phones. But when it comes to tablet, all the images are looking small in size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the 4x images too for the biggest like tablet

My advice for this is to use as much as possible the vector icons to avoid this kind of trouble at least for icons.

---

Check this post out :  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4041